# Python Munging - Best practice with DataFrame variables

Tags: python, pandas

In R, with data munging. I generally do most if not all my basic munging in one go through piping e.g.

```
df_mung = df %>% 
  filter(X > 1) %>% 
  select(X, Y, Z) %>% 
  group_by(X, Y) %>% 
  summarise(`sum` = sum(Z))
```

Which means, in this example, at the end I have two DataFrames:

1. `df` (my original DataFrame)
2. `df_mung` (my munged DataFrame))

If I was to do this in Python, I would do something like this:

```
df_filter = df[df['X']>1]
df_select = df_filter[['X', 'Y', 'Z']]
df_sum = df_select.groupby(['X','Y']).sum()
```

Which leaves me with four DataFrames (double the amount I had in R):

1. `df` (my original DataFrame)
2. `df_filter` (my filtered DataFrame)
3. `df_select` (my selected columns DataFrame)
4. `df_sum` (my summed DataFrame))

Now I could copy my DataFrame back on to itself, like this:

```
df = df['X']>1
df = df[['X', 'Y', 'Z']]
df = df.groupby(['X','Y']).sum()
```

But given the highly upvoted response in this post for `SettingWithCopyWarning`: [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas) , this is apparently something I should not be doing.

So my question is, what is the best practice when data munging in Python? Creating a new variable each time I do something, or copying the DataFrame onto itself, or something else?

I am worried that when I do a piece of analysis in Python, I could have tens if not hundreds of DataFrame variables which a) looks messy b) is confusing to people who take over my code.

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd just wrap the munging in a function.

- the intermediate variables are not in any global scope (not messy)
- the munging function does a single, comprehensible thing (not confusing for people reading your code)
- the munging function is testable in isolation (good practice).

```
def munge_df(df):
    df_filter = df['X'] > 1
    df_select = df_filter[['X', 'Y', 'Z']]
    df_sum = df_select.groupby(['X','Y']).sum()
    return df_sum

# ...

df_munged = munge_df(df)  # or just `df = ...` if you don't need the original
```

Comment: Hey AKX, that is so helpful. I had never thought about doing it that way and I have been doing this for years. Thats a really clean way of doing things and as you said, not confusing at all for people reading my code.... super thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could skip the `SettingWithCopyWarning` using `loc` and do the filtering of rows and columns in one expression. You could also do method chaining which seems like what you are doing in the R example.

`df.loc[df['X'].gt(1), ['X', 'Y', 'Z']].groupby(['X', 'Y']).sum()`

Comment: Hey Anders, thank you for your response. I do need to look more into piping in Python, or the equivalent formatting and I was aware of .loc, with the SettingWithCopyWarning.. I guess bad example ha!

Comment: You basically can chain all methods as long as you know what they output - a DataFrame, a Series, a GroupBy object etc. I think there is a typo in your example. The filtered DataFrame should probably be df_filter = df[df['X']>1]? Otherwise you will just get a Series of booleans.

Comment: Ahh, ye. Thanks. I will make the edit and interesting to know! :)